# Virtual interface statistics on Linux

Tags: linux, networking, virtualization, device

I am trying to get statistics about virtual interfaces I have configured on my Linux box running Ubuntu.  `/proc/net/dev` contains entries for `lo` and `eth1`, but I also have two virtual interfaces, `lo:2` and `eth1:1`, which are not reported.

After some research, it seems like the virtual interfaces are just a layer on top of the kernel, but the kernel is still only handling the actual interfaces, so it cannot report statistics for the virtual interfaces.

I have read that using [ipchains](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IPCHAINS-HOWTO.html) it is possible to get these statistics, but this introduces some significant administrative overhead which I would like to avoid.

Does anyone know how to get these statistics (received bytes, transmitted bytes, etc.) for virtual interfaces on Linux running Ubuntu?

Thanks!

Comment: Virtual interfaces as you describe are deprecated.

Comment: @MikeyB Can you explain what you mean, or give a link to the correct undeprecated link?  I can't seem to find any other way of setting up virtual interfaces.

Comment: The new iproute2 utilities are what you should be using to set up additional IPs. (I.e.: ip addr add 10.23.54.67/24 dev eth0). Kevin is correct; you need to use iptables for accounting.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible without adding in a layer like iptables/ipchains.  If anything could get the data netstat would, and `netstat -ian` will show you "no statistics available" for virtual interfaces.